# Windows 2008-R2 User re-created issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-7, domain

All our users in a organizational unit got removed by accident. I used Microsoft guide to recover these users, however after using the recommended cmdlette the usersname is no where to be found. The OU was found and restored. Luckly I only had 5 users in that OU.

The issue is I re-created the users. Now when the users logs into domain, a new profile is created?!?!

Could I repoint the domain profile to the correct profile? I REALLY don't want to deal with new profiles for each of the 5 users. Any advice would be great!

So the question is, how could the user load their orginal domain profile instead of the new userprofile?

Comment: I asked you this in an earlier comment and I will keep downvoting you until you answer it since it is a critical piece of information that you're leaving out. **How did you restore the objects?** Did you do a tombstone reanimation? Did you use the recycle bin cmdlets? Did you restore from a backup using ntdsutil?

Comment: I used tombstone reanimation, but after I usered the cmdlet below, I could not find the deleted OU or users. I used: Get-ADObject -SearchBase "CN=Deleted Objects,DC=Jones-Stuckey,DC=Local" -ldapFilter:"(msDs-lastKnownRDN=Columbus)" –IncludeDeletedObjects –Properties lastKnownParent

Comment: I checked AD, and could not find the OU. Checked ldp.exe and Deleted Objects was empty.

Comment: Do you have the AD Recycle Bin enabled in your environment? That only works if it's enabled. A tombstone reanimation isn't a real restore. If you can't restore from the recycle bin, your best bet is to authoritatively restore the users from a recent system state backup.

Comment: Somebody appears to have done something quite nasty to your environment. You don't appear to have the knowledge or skills  to deal with this (having read your other related questions). This really is a situation where paying someone with he skills will be your best option.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to go to each server/workstation and copy the contents of the profile. You can do this programmatically with some scripting, but it will require either manual intervention or custom code. The best way would be to actually restore the users correctly. If you don't have the AD Recycle Bin enabled, you should use an authoritative AD restore from your system state backups (you have those, right?) to restore the user accounts exactly as they were.

Short of a proper restore, it will be a bit of a headache for you unless you're comfortable in a scripting language.